# Creating this poster layout using minipages

Tags: positioning, minipage, posters, tikzposter

I am making a poster in LaTeX. I am using the minipages enviroment to split the poster into three columns. I have some boxes which spread over multiple columns. The difficulty arises when I try to have two boxes which spread over 2 different seperate columns.

How can I arrange this layout using minipages? The issue is getting the bottom arrangement to work.

### Desired output

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[final,a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{quantum,natbib,graphicx,placeins,rotating,bm,amsbsy,amsmath,mathrsfs,caption,mathtools}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx,float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage[font=Large,justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}   
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\floatplacement{table}{H}
\floatplacement{tabular}{H}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{Blue!50}

\Large

\tcbset{center title, left=35pt,right=35pt,top=35pt,bottom=35pt, colback=white,colframe=DarkBlue!80,title=\textcolor{White}, toptitle=0.5cm, bottomtitle=0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.19\linewidth}

\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.27cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.62\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\color{White}
\Huge \color{White}  \textbf{\textsf{Title here}} \\
\huge \textsf{Name1\textsuperscript{*} and Name2$^\dagger$}\\  \Large
\emph{Department} \\ \textsuperscript{*}    \textit{email1}, $^\dagger$\textit{email2}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
%a
\hspace{0.27cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\linewidth}

\end{minipage}


\vspace{1cm}


%Top Left
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.64\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textcolor{White}{\huge\textsf{Title 1}}]
Some text
\vspace{5cm}
\end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{20pt}
%
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.485\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=10pt, bottom=10pt, title=\textcolor{White}{\huge\textsf{Title 2}}]
a
\vspace{60.8cm}

a
\end{tcolorbox} % THIS IS THE END OF THE QFI TEXT BOX

\end{minipage} 
%
%
\quad
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=10pt, bottom=10pt, title=\textcolor{White}{\huge\textsf{Title 3}}]
\vspace{0.8cm}
\noindent
Some text
\vspace{25.5cm}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[top=10pt, bottom=10pt, title=\textcolor{White}{\huge\textsf{Title 4}}]
\vspace{0.8cm}
\noindent
Some text
\vspace{30cm}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{minipage} 


\end{minipage} 
%
\quad
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textcolor{White}{\huge\textsf{Title 5}}]
Some text
\vspace{65cm}
a
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=40pt,bottom=40pt,title=\textcolor{White}{\huge\textsf{Title 6}}]
Some text
\vspace{5cm}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth} 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.61\linewidth} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=40pt, bottom=40pt, title=\textcolor{White}{\huge\textsf{References}}]

\vspace{10cm}

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your image link didn't work, upload it directly to your post instead (there's a button for image upload right above the text input field, keyboard shortcut Ctrl + G).

Comment: Can you show us a minimal working example showing the minipages you have, so we have *something* to *fix* ?

Comment: @marsupilam, how can I show it? Even the MWE is quite long.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, the image was wrong. It has been updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Motivated by the answers of @Ignasi, I made a new library `poster` for `tcolorbox` which is part of the package starting with version `4.10 (2017/07/06)`.

The main purpose of the new library is (of course) the support of `tcolorbox` placement for posters in a similar manner as `baposter` does.

I took the two examples of @Ignasi with his definition of a private `posterbox` style and modified them for the new library. I hope you will find that the new library allows to write the code much shorter and better readable:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most,poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
    posterbox/.style={%
        enhanced jigsaw, size=fbox,
        colback=#1!10, colframe=#1!10!black,
        colbacktitle=#1!70!black
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
  coverage={spread,phantom=\thispagestyle{empty}},
  poster={columns=3,rows=8,spacing=3mm,showframe=false},
  fontsize=12pt,
]

\posterbox[title=Top left box,posterbox=blue]{name=A,column=1,below=top,span=2,rowspan=1}
{This is some other text}

\posterbox[title=Bottom right box,posterbox=blue]{name=B,column=2,above=bottom,span=2,rowspan=1}
{This is some other text}

\posterbox[title=Bottom left box,posterbox=green]{name=C,column=1,between=A and bottom}
{This is some other text}

\posterbox[title=Central box,posterbox=red]{name=D,column=2,between=A and B}
{This is some other text}

\posterbox[title=Top right box,posterbox=green]{name=E,column=3,between=top and B}
{This is some other text}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example uses a breakable box. Note that this box can be used directly with the new library:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most,poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
    posterbox/.style={%
        enhanced jigsaw, size=fbox,
        colback=#1!10, colframe=#1!10!black,
        colbacktitle=#1!70!black
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
  coverage={spread,phantom=\thispagestyle{empty}},
  poster={columns=3,rows=8,spacing=3mm,showframe=false},
  fontsize=12pt,
]

\posterbox[title=Top left box,posterbox=blue]{name=A,column=1,below=top,span=2,rowspan=1}
{This is some other text}

\posterbox[title=Bottom right box,posterbox=blue]{name=B,column=2,above=bottom,span=2,rowspan=1}
{This is some other text}

\posterbox[title=Some long text,posterbox=orange]{name=C,
  sequence=1 between A and bottom then
           2 between A and B then
           3 between top and B }
{\lipsum[1-5]}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The box dimensions are settable by way of

```
\def\Vgap{3pt}
\def\Hgap{3pt}
\def\VsizeA{4in}
\def\HsizeA{1.4in}
\def\VsizeB{0.5in}
```

as well as `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.  Note that the 3 `\?size` dimensions are the `minipage` dimensions, before `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` get applied.

The MWE.

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\fpage[3]{\unskip%
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][#2][t]{#1}\LARGE #3\end{minipage}}\ignorespaces}
\def\Vgap{3pt}
\def\Hgap{3pt}
\def\VsizeA{4in}
\def\HsizeA{1.4in}
\def\VsizeB{0.5in}
% THE FOLLOWING ARE DERIVED
\def\HsizeB{2\dimexpr\HsizeA\relax+\dimexpr\Hgap\relax+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}
\def\VsizeC{%
  \dimexpr\VsizeA-\dimexpr\VsizeB\relax-\dimexpr\Vgap\relax-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\def\doHgap{\unskip\hspace{\Hgap}\ignorespaces}
\def\HsizeC{\HsizeA}
\setstackgap{S}{\Vgap}
%
\begin{document}
\stackon{
 \fpage{\HsizeA}{\VsizeA}{A1}\doHgap
 \stackon{
   \fpage{\HsizeB}{\VsizeB}{B2}%
 }{%
   \fpage{\HsizeC}{\VsizeC}{C}\doHgap
   \smash{\fpage{\HsizeA}{\VsizeA}{A2}}%
 }%
}{
  \fpage{\HsizeB}{\VsizeB}{B1}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here with

```
\def\Vgap{5pt}
\def\Hgap{5pt}
\def\VsizeA{6in}
\def\HsizeA{1.4in}
\def\VsizeB{1.5in}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Here is a version without the `\fbox`es and with `\lipsum` fill

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\fpage[3]{\unskip%
  \begin{minipage}[b][#2][t]{#1}\tiny#3\end{minipage}\ignorespaces}
\def\Vgap{8pt}
\def\Hgap{8pt}
\def\VsizeA{7.5in}
\def\HsizeA{2in}
\def\VsizeB{2in}
% THE FOLLOWING ARE DERIVED
\def\HsizeB{2\dimexpr\HsizeA\relax+\dimexpr\Hgap\relax}
\def\VsizeC{%
  \dimexpr\VsizeA-\dimexpr\VsizeB\relax-\dimexpr\Vgap\relax\relax}
\def\doHgap{\unskip\hspace{\Hgap}\ignorespaces}
\def\HsizeC{\HsizeA}
\setstackgap{S}{\Vgap}
%
\begin{document}
\stackon{
 \fpage{\HsizeA}{\VsizeA}{A1 \lipsum[1]}\doHgap
 \stackon{
   \fpage{\HsizeB}{\VsizeB}{B2 \lipsum[4]}%
 }{%
   \fpage{\HsizeC}{\VsizeC}{C \lipsum[3]}\doHgap
   \smash{\fpage{\HsizeA}{\VsizeA}{A2 \lipsum[5]}}%
 }%
}{
  \fpage{\HsizeB}{\VsizeB}{B1 \lipsum[4]}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome ! Can you show how us to not draw the minipages borders, and fill with lipsum ?

Comment: @marsupilam See my **ADDENDUM**.

Comment: Great answer. Just a few questions: since I am using \tcolorboxes, would I just place them where the contents are? Also how would you control the gap between each column?

Comment: @Sid  The inter-column gap is set by `\Hgap`, defined in the preamble.  I don't use `tcolorbox`, but I would presume you would get rid of the `\tiny` (or `\LARGE`) in my definition of `\fpage` and then pass the `tcolorbox` commands as the last argument to `\fpage`.

Answer (score 6):

Following code uses `TikZ` nodes and `positioning` library to place these five boxes as desired. But in this case the node contents is formed by `tcolorboxes` with defined dimensions.

First, boxes width and height are defined (inspired by [Steven B. Segletes answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375724/1952)):

```
\setlength{\Vgap}{8pt}
\setlength{\Hgap}{8pt}
\setlength{\HsizeA}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-2\Hgap)/3}
\setlength{\VsizeB}{\HsizeA} %<-- Fix this value

% THE FOLLOWING ARE DERIVED
\setlength{\VsizeA}{\dimexpr\textheight-\Vgap-\VsizeB}
\setlength{\HsizeB}{\dimexpr2\HsizeA+\Hgap}
\setlength{\VsizeC}{\dimexpr\VsizeA-\VsizeB-\Vgap}
\setlength{\HsizeC}{\HsizeA}
```

These lengths will be use to define three kind of boxes:

`myboxA` are the boxes for the external columns

```
\newtcolorbox{myboxA}[2][]{%
    posterbox=green,
    width=\HsizeA, height=\VsizeA, 
    title=#2, #1}
```

top and bottom boxes are of type `myboxB`

```
\newtcolorbox{myboxB}[2][]{%
    posterbox=blue,
    width=\HsizeB, height=\VsizeB, 
    title=#2, #1}
```

and finaly the central box which is of type `myboxC`

```
\newtcolorbox{myboxC}[2][]{%
    posterbox=red,
    width=\HsizeC, height=\VsizeC, 
    title=#2, #1}
```

These boxes are inserted as `text` of `TikZ` nodes with `inner sep=0pt` and `outer sep=0pt` (fixing `seps` to `0pt` is important because otherwise the placement will fail)

```
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt}]
\node (B1) {%
    \begin{myboxB}{Top left box}
        This is some other text
    \end{myboxB}};

\node[right= \Hgap of B1.north east, anchor=north west] (A2) {%
    \begin{myboxA}{Top right box}
        This is some other text
    \end{myboxA}};

...
```

The result will look like more or less like desired:

[image]

Previous solution assumes that all five boxes are independent but in case that the text should flow between them, `magazine` library from `tcolorbox` can help.
As an example, suppose that all three columns should contain fragments of a certain text. In this case it's possible to define a box like:

```
\newtcolorbox{brokenbox}[2][]{%
    posterbox=orange,
    width=\HsizeA,
    breakable,
    break at=\VsizeA/\VsizeC/\VsizeA, 
    height fixed for=all,   
    reset box array,
    store to box array,
    title=#2,#1}
```

which will store its contents in several fragments that can be later on printed with `useboxarray` command. In final code you'll find:

```
\begin{brokenbox}{Some long text} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{brokenbox}
```

which defines the box, breaks it and store the fragments which are printed with

```
...
\node[right= \Hgap of B1.north east, anchor=north west] (A2) {\useboxarray{3}};

\node[below = \Vgap of B1.south west, anchor=north west] (A1) {\useboxarray{1}};
...
```

The result in this case is:

[image]

A similar result could be done with text flowing from top to bottom wide boxes.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength\Vgap
\newlength\Hgap
\newlength\VsizeA
\newlength\VsizeB
\newlength\VsizeC
\newlength\HsizeA
\newlength\HsizeB
\newlength\HsizeC

\setlength{\Vgap}{8pt}
\setlength{\Hgap}{8pt}
\setlength{\HsizeA}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-2\Hgap)/3}
\setlength{\VsizeB}{\HsizeA} %<-- Fix this value

% THE FOLLOWING ARE DERIVED
\setlength{\VsizeA}{\dimexpr\textheight-\Vgap-\VsizeB}
\setlength{\HsizeB}{\dimexpr2\HsizeA+\Hgap}
\setlength{\VsizeC}{\dimexpr\VsizeA-\VsizeB-\Vgap}
\setlength{\HsizeC}{\HsizeA}

\tcbset{
    posterbox/.style={%
        enhanced jigsaw, size=fbox, 
        colback=#1!10, colframe=#1!10!black, 
        colbacktitle=#1!70!black
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{myboxA}[2][]{%
    posterbox=green,
    width=\HsizeA, height=\VsizeA, 
    title=#2, #1}

\newtcolorbox{myboxB}[2][]{%
    posterbox=blue,
    width=\HsizeB, height=\VsizeB, 
    title=#2, #1}

\newtcolorbox{myboxC}[2][]{%
    posterbox=red,
    width=\HsizeC, height=\VsizeC, 
    title=#2, #1}

\newtcolorbox{brokenbox}[2][]{%
    posterbox=orange,
    width=\HsizeA,
    breakable,
    break at=\VsizeA/\VsizeC/\VsizeA, 
    height fixed for=all,   
    reset box array,
    store to box array,
    title=#2,#1}

\begin{brokenbox}{Some long text} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{brokenbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt}]
\node (B1) {%
    \begin{myboxB}{Top left box}
        This is some other text
    \end{myboxB}};

\node[right= \Hgap of B1.north east, anchor=north west] (A2) {%
    \begin{myboxA}{Top right box}
        This is some other text
    \end{myboxA}};

\node[below = \Vgap of B1.south west, anchor=north west] (A1) {%
    \begin{myboxA}{Bottom left box}
        This is some other text
    \end{myboxA}};

\node[right = \Hgap of A1.north east, anchor=north west] (C) {%
    \begin{myboxC}{Central box}
        This is some other text
    \end{myboxC}};

\node[below = \Vgap of C.south west, anchor=north west] (B2) {%
    \begin{myboxB}{Bottom rigth box}
        Some other text
    \end{myboxB}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt}]
\node (B1) {\begin{myboxB}{Top left box}This is some other text\end{myboxB}};

\node[right= \Hgap of B1.north east, anchor=north west] (A2) {\useboxarray{3}};

\node[below = \Vgap of B1.south west, anchor=north west] (A1) {\useboxarray{1}};

\node[right = \Hgap of A1.north east, anchor=north west] (C) {\useboxarray{2}};

\node[below = \Vgap of C.south west, anchor=north west] (B2) {\begin{myboxB}[colback=red!20]{Bottom rigth box}Some other text\end{myboxB}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note: My initial intention was to use a `tcbraster` to place the boxes but I couldn't and finally did it with `TikZ`. I'm open to suggestions or comments  about this option.

Comment: I added a new answer based on the new `poster` library and your two examples.

Answer (score 3):

Another tool for posters which allow us to define complex layouts like this one is [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/) (it's not on [CTAN](http://ctan.org)).

`baposter` define different kind of boxes which can be placed on a multicolumn and multirow structure. These boxes has a `name` which can be used for relative placement but also to define later declared boxes size.

For portrait posters the default column number is 3 (`columns` option define this number between 1 to 6). Then we can use

```
\headerbox{Top left}{name=topleft, column=0, row=0, span=2}{
    \lipsum[1]
}
```

to define the first box, which is placed on first column and first row but will span for 2 columns. Below this box we want another one which spans only one column but it covers all vertical space between the top box and poster's bottom:

```
\headerbox{Left Column}{name=leftcolumn, column=0, below=topleft, above=bottom}{
    \lipsum[2-4]
}
```

The use of `below` and `above` options in previous command forces the vertical size. If we only use `below` the box would be as large as needed but not enlarged to the bottom.

With previous examples is easy to understand following code and result:

```
\documentclass[portrait,final,a0paper,fontscale=0.277]{baposter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Here starts the poster
%%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Format it to your taste with the options
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Define some colors

%%
\begin{poster}%
  % Poster Options
  {
  % Show grid to help with alignment
  grid=false,
  % Column spacing
  colspacing=1em,
  % Color style
  bgColorOne=white,
  bgColorTwo=white,
  borderColor=blue,
  headerColorOne=black,
  headerColorTwo=blue,
  headerFontColor=white,
  boxColorOne=white,
  boxColorTwo=blue,
  % Format of textbox
  textborder=roundedleft,
  % Format of text header
  eyecatcher=true,
  headerborder=closed,
  headerheight=0.1\textheight,
%  textfont=\sc, An example of changing the text font
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=shadelr,
  headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
  textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}},
  boxshade=plain,
%  background=shade-tb,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
  % Eye Catcher
  {\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-a}} 
  % Title
  {\bf\textsc{My poster}\vspace{0.5em}}
  % Authors
  {\textsc{\{ xxx \}@xxx.xx}}
  % University logo
  {% The makebox allows the title to flow into the logo, this is a hack because of the L shaped logo.
    \includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-b}
  }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Now define the boxes that make up the poster
%%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Each box has a name and can be placed absolutely or relatively.
%%% The only inconvenience is that you can only specify a relative position 
%%% towards an already declared box. So if you have a box attached to the 
%%% bottom, one to the top and a third one which should be in between, you 
%%% have to specify the top and bottom boxes before you specify the middle 
%%% box.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  \headerbox{Top left}{name=topleft, column=0, row=0, span=2}{
   \lipsum[1]
 }

  \headerbox{Left Column}{name=leftcolumn,column=0,below=topleft, above=bottom}{
   \lipsum[2-4]
  }

  \headerbox{Bottom right}{name=bottomright,column=1,span=2,above=bottom}{
    \lipsum[2]
  }

  \headerbox{Right column}{name=rightcolumn,column=2,row=0, above=bottomright}{
    \lipsum[3]
  }
  \headerbox{Central column}{name=centralcolumn model,column=1,below=topleft, above=bottomright}{
   \lipsum[5]
  }

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compared with `tcolorbox`, `baposter` provides an easier placement system but box styles are far more limited.