# Create Page layout with beautiful boxes/tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, posters

from this topic: [Inspired beautiful box from Indesign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281375/inspired-beautiful-box-from-indesign/340938#340938).
Now, i want create page layout with differentboxes like attachment image.
Use tcbposter if possible or other solution.
Thanks
This boxes code:
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\input{insbox}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    myhbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        breakable,
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight}, 
        title={#2},
        boxed title size=title,
        boxed title style={%
            sharp corners, 
            rounded corners=northwest, 
            colback=tcbcol@frame, 
            boxrule=0pt,
        },
        underlay boxed title={%
            \path[fill=tcbcol@frame] (title.south west)--(title.south east) 
                to[out=0, in=180] ([xshift=5mm]title.east)--
                (title.center-|frame.east)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] |- 
                (frame.north) -| cycle; 
        },
        #1
    },
    myvbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        left=8mm,
        overlay={
            \node[rotate=90, anchor=north west, inner sep=2mm, text=white] (title@aux) at (frame.south west) {#2};
            \path[fill=tcbcol@frame] (title@aux.south west)--(title@aux.south east) 
                to[out=90, in=270] ([yshift=5mm]title@aux.east)--
                (title@aux.center|-frame.north)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] -| 
                (frame.west) |- (title@aux.west)[sharp corners] -- cycle;   
            \node[rotate=90, inner sep=2mm, text=white] at (title@aux) {#2};
        },
        #1
    },  
}   

\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{myhbox}[2][]{%
    myhbox={#1}{#2}
}

\newtcolorbox{myvbox}[2][]{%
    myvbox={#1}{#2}
}
\begin{document}



\begin{myhbox}[colframe=blue!80!black,height=3cm,width =7cm]{AAA}{

def
}
\end{myhbox}

\begin{myhbox}[colframe=blue!80!black,height=3cm,width =7cm]
{BBB }{
abc
}
\end{myhbox}


  \begin{myvbox}[colframe=red!80!black,height=6cm,width =4cm,before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup,after=\egroup]{CCC}


    { 
   abcdef
    }% 

\end{myvbox}
\begin{myvbox}[colframe=red!80!black,height=6cm,width =4cm,before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup,after=\egroup]{DDD}


    { 
   abcdef
    }% 

\end{myvbox}

\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {
%       showframe, 
        columns = 2,
        rows = 2,
        height = .5\textheight, 
        width = .5\textwidth, 
        spacing=3mm},
    boxes = {colback=red}
    ]
    \begin{posterbox}{column=1, row=1}[colframe=red!80!black,height=6cm,width =4cm]{ABCD}
   \end{posterbox}
  \end{tcbposter}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at `tcbraster`. The example on page 281 of the `tcolorbox` manual might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that BVOT wants boxes with specific dimensions:

> Ex: A4 paper width size = 29.7 cm and i want total (all column boxes = 27 cm) and box CCC width = 15 cm, AAA width = 5 cm and BBB width = 7 cm.

In this case it's easier to use `tcbposter`. A `tcbposter` is an initial regular distribution of columns and rows over which place boxes with reference to columns, rows and other boxes.

As desired boxes widths are not proportional, I've used a `tcbposter` with just two columns. Left box will be aligned to left and right boxes to the right. The middle box on first row will be placed `xshifted` from the left border.

Proposed dimensions don't allow space between columns, therefore I've reduced left box and first column right box get some separation between columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[textwidth=27cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    myhbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        breakable,
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight}, 
        title={#2},
        boxed title size=title,
        boxed title style={%
            sharp corners, 
            rounded corners=northwest, 
            colback=tcbcolframe, 
            boxrule=0pt,
        },
        underlay boxed title={%
            \path[fill=tcbcolframe] (title.south west)--(title.south east) 
                to[out=0, in=180] ([xshift=5mm]title.east)--
                (title.center-|frame.east)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] |- 
                (frame.north) -| cycle; 
        },
        #1
    },
    myvbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        left=8mm,
        overlay={
            \node[rotate=90, anchor=north west, inner sep=2mm, text=white] (title@aux) at (frame.south west) {#2};
            \path[fill=tcbcolframe] (title@aux.south west)--(title@aux.south east) 
                to[out=90, in=270] ([yshift=5mm]title@aux.east)--
                (title@aux.center|-frame.north)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] -| 
                (frame.west) |- (title@aux.west)[sharp corners] -- cycle;   
            \node[rotate=90, inner sep=2mm, text=white] at (title@aux) {#2};
        },
        #1
    },  
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent%
\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster = {columns=2, rows=2, width=\textwidth, height=\textheight}]
\posterbox[width=15cm-\tcbpostercolspacing, myvbox={colframe=red!80!black}{CCC}]{column=1, row=1, rowspan=2}{CCC}
\posterbox[width=5cm, myhbox={}{AAA}]{column=1, row=1, xshift=15cm}{AAA}
\posterbox[width=7cm-\tcbpostercolspacing, myhbox={}{BBB}]{column*=2, row=1}{BBB}
\posterbox[width=12cm, myhbox={}{DDD}]{column*=2, row=2}{DDD}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note* Previous code has been updated for compatibility with tcolorbox v4.20. If you're using previous versions, rename colors with form `tcbcol...` to older form  `tcbcol@...`.

Comment: Ignasi. How can you edit distance between these boxes: height & width distance?

Comment: @BVOT `tcbposter` options `rowspacing` and `colspacing` (4mm by default) will fix these distances. See [tcolorbox.pdf](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=401).

Comment: @BVOT About how this place works, you could read https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote and https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: done with vote and accepted answer. many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This distributions are also possible with `tcbraster`. Here you have some examples. More information in [`tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=277) documentation

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    myhbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        breakable,
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight}, 
        title={#2},
        boxed title size=title,
        boxed title style={%
            sharp corners, 
            rounded corners=northwest, 
            colback=tcbcolframe, 
            boxrule=0pt,
        },
        underlay boxed title={%
            \path[fill=tcbcolframe] (title.south west)--(title.south east) 
                to[out=0, in=180] ([xshift=5mm]title.east)--
                (title.center-|frame.east)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] |- 
                (frame.north) -| cycle; 
        },
        #1
    },
    myvbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        left=8mm,
        overlay={
            \node[rotate=90, anchor=north west, inner sep=2mm, text=white] (title@aux) at (frame.south west) {#2};
            \path[fill=tcbcolframe] (title@aux.south west)--(title@aux.south east) 
                to[out=90, in=270] ([yshift=5mm]title@aux.east)--
                (title@aux.center|-frame.north)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] -| 
                (frame.west) |- (title@aux.west)[sharp corners] -- cycle;   
            \node[rotate=90, inner sep=2mm, text=white] at (title@aux) {#2};
        },
        #1
    },  
}   
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{myhbox}[2][]{%
    myhbox={#1}{#2}
}

\newtcolorbox{myvbox}[2][]{%
    myvbox={#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster columns=2, 
    raster rows=2, 
    raster equal height=rows,
    ]
    \tcbitem[blankest]
        \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1]
            \tcbitem[myhbox={}{AAA}]    First box with horizontal title
            \tcbitem[myhbox={}{AAA}]    Second box with horizontal title
        \end{tcbitemize}
    \tcbitem[myvbox={colframe=red!70!black}{CCC}]Box with vertical title
\end{tcbitemize}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster columns=5, 
    raster rows=2, 
    raster equal height=rows,
    ]
    \tcbitem[raster multirow=2, raster multicolumn=3, blankest]
        \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1]
            \tcbitem[myhbox={}{AAA}]    First box with horizontal title
            \tcbitem[myhbox={}{AAA}]    Second box with horizontal title
        \end{tcbitemize}
    \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, myvbox={colframe=red!70!black}{CCC}]Box with vertical title
\end{tcbitemize}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster columns=3, 
    raster rows=2, 
    raster equal height=rows,
    ]
    \tcbitem[raster multirow=2, myvbox={colframe=red!70!black}{CCC}]Box with vertical title
    \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, blankest]
        \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2]
            \tcbitem[myhbox={}{AAA}]    First box with horizontal title
            \tcbitem[myhbox={}{BBB}]    Second box with horizontal title
            \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, myhbox={}{BBB}] Double horizontal box
        \end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note* Previous code has been updated for compatibility with tcolorbox v4.20. If you're using previous versions, rename colors with form `tcbcol...` to older form  `tcbcol@...`.

Comment: How can i use dimension ưith mm, cm for each box height, box width? Thanks

Comment: Ex: A4 paper width size = 29.7 cm and i want total (all column boxes = 27 cm) and box CCC width = 15 cm, AAA width = 5 cm and BBB width = 7 cm. Thanks

Comment: @BVOT Receiving a thanks message is nice, but some upvote and/or even some accepted answer are also welcome. By the way, I've written another answer with `tcbposter` and boxes with specific dimensions.

Comment: thanks. tcbposter with your new code is easier.